# How to link "Franck the sheep" to a scene

Tags: import

I'm a noob who (for about 20 years now) once in a while plays around with blender. I now downloaded blender 2.83 and the gooseberry-benchmark-scnene. To be able to play around with the sheep I subscribed to blender cloud and downloaded the fully animatable character, but I'm not able to link it to the scene according to the instructions, because I can't find a "CH-Franck_sheep" which should be choosen (s. https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5d40511bfe6b50fb62faea7d).
I found a "franck_sheep_high", but that only seems to be the model without the rig,...
Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know much about that high sheep, but if you can't find the file then keep looking

Comment: There is nothing that begins with "ch"!

Comment: What does the CH stand for ?
There probably is those under a different name, try to stop following tutorials and you might realize that you are not a newbie anymore.

Comment: @Mick Are you "inside" the blend file and looking at the **collection names**?

Comment: There are tons of folders and "names": Action, Armature, Brush, ...

Comment: ...inside the .blend file!

Comment: I now opened the sheep by double clicking on it and then it opens with everything in it. As in the browser the top entrance is "Scene collection" i suppose that the "scene" within the .blend-file was loaded, but when i try to link the scene to an existing scene, nothing happens.

Comment: The author of the (2019 version) of the sheep fixed it now